# Navigation drawer Activity with two backgrounds

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a `navigation Drawer Activity` with two groups as shown in the image.
What I want is for a group to have a background of a blue example color and the other white group.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

[image]

This is my code **Activity Main Drawer.xml**

Here I have the two groups for group 1 I want to put a color and for group 2 I want to put another one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group
    android:id="@+id/grupo1"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_perfil"
        android:title="Mi Perfil" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_inbox"
        android:title="MiInbox" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_aliados"
        android:title="Mis aliados" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_favoritos"
        android:title="Mis favoritos" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_preferencias"
        android:title="Mis preferencias y privacidad" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_ordenes"
        android:title="Mis ordenes" />

</group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/grupo2"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_empresasDestacadas"
            android:title="Empresas destacadas" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_cercaDeMi"
            android:title="Cerca de mi" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_oportunidades"
            android:title="Oportunidades" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_noticias"
            android:title="Noticias" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_empresas"
            android:title="Empresas" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profesionales"
            android:title="Profesionales" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_eventos"
            android:title="Eventos" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_productos"
            android:title="Productos" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_licitaciones"
            android:title="Licitaciones" />

    </group>
 </menu>
```

Comment: Have you tried `android:background`?

Comment: yes sir but change the two groups of color

Comment: Right, you have two `<group`, so put it in each one

Comment: I already put the two different backgrounds and still shows one